# Publisher mapError with the Combine Framework

Tags: swift, combine

I have a setup like this with an error shown below

```
enum DataError: Error {
    case failed(error: Error)
}

enum UIError: Error {
    case failed(error: Error)
}

struct SomeData {

}

func foo() -> AnyPublisher<Result<[SomeData]?, DataError>, Never> {
    ...
}

func foo2() -> AnyPublisher<Result<[SomeData]?, UIError>, Never> {
    return foo()
            .mapError { error -> UIError 
                switch error {
                    ....
                }

                return UIError.failed(error: $0)
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher() ===> // Error Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<Result<[SomeData]?, DataError>, UIError>' to return type 'AnyPublisher<Result<[T], UIError>, Never>'
}
```

The error message seem pretty straight forward but cant quite resolve it.

Comment: Without seeing your implementation of `foo()` this is largely pointless, as your code can never be tested in the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need something like this:

The Publisher returns no Error. The Result has the error so you need to mapError the Result.

I modified the Error enums a bit to make it easier to understand.

```
    enum DataError: Error {
        case failed
    }

    enum UIError: Error {
        case failed
    }

    func foo2() -> AnyPublisher<Result<[SomeData]?, UIError>, Never> {
        return foo().map { result in
            result.mapError { _ -> UIError in
                UIError.failed
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in using `Result` in `Combine`, since your `Publisher`s will always either emit a value or complete with failure. They should never emit a value, which contains an error.

Once you get rid of your usage of `Result`, the errors go away nicely.

```
func foo() -> AnyPublisher<[SomeData], DataError> {
    ...
}

func foo2() -> AnyPublisher<[SomeData], UIError> {
    return foo()
        .mapError { error -> UIError in
            switch error {
            ...
            }

            return UIError.failed(error: error)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Either with `Result` or in a `Publisher`, you usually don't need to use `Optional`s, since in case of error, there simply won't be a value, there's no need to return `nil` value, unlike with completion handlers.

Comment: Thanks @David for the suggestion; point taken, however it doesn't quite answer the questions. Do you have any response to resolving the current implementations error?

Comment: @user3355301 why do you want to fix a solution that has a fundamental flaw in it rather than fix that fundamental flaw?

Comment: There is a Result publisher so Result _is_ useful — it is a publisher.